# Excluding interactions from event we put on as a company

Tags: google, custom-dimensions

We have a SaaS offering (we call it "the Hub"), which we use as part of (IRL) events that we put on as a company, Mainly to demo our expertise in our field, but also to demo the Hub. As part of the demo, we get attendees to get onboard and use the Hub.

Obviously these appear in our analytics, but are skewing the figures we want, which is essentialy: how many interactions / GA events do we get OUTSIDE of the interactions generated by one of our (IRL) Demo events?

I already have the logic in the application to take a reasonable stab at "Is this interaction part of a hub demonstration" So that's covered, my question is, how do I let GA know about it, and effectively report/filter on it?

Im assuming its something to do with custom dimensions, probably event scoped, but any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UTM parameters or codes to distinguish them. There are 5 of them, but 3 are the most used:

1. **UTM Medium:** Think of them as a channel category. For example, Social for social shares, IRL for your real-life events, etc.
2. **UTM Source:** it will be like more granular tracking of the previous one. Say if you went with Social for Medium, your source could be Facebook, Twitter, etc. For your IRL, it could be, "Hub Florida" or something.
3. **UTM Campaign:** the specific campaign you are running. For example, "Booth Site Demo", or "QR Code", etc.

Here's an example of how to implement it:

example.com/demo/?**utm_medium**=IRL&**utm_source**=Florida%20HUB&**utm_campaign**=Booth%20Site%20Demo